# PHP Unable to write the content in PDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

After executing the below code, Browser automatically Downloading PDF Document. When i open that PDF, i am getting below Error.

[image]
I got below snippet idea from [source](http://www.michikono.com/2007/03/28/php-nuisance-how-to-stream-pdf-files/)

```
<?php
$filename = "yourfilename.pdf";
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo "my contents should display in PDF Document";
?>
```

Comment: I believe `pdf raw binary data` is a bit different from plain text.

Comment: i would like to know. to print plain text, what should i do ?

Comment: Use a PDF library to generate a valid PDF document I'd guess.

Comment: you mean TCPDF. This TCODF looks like we have to mention header footer and have to concentrate on the design parts and so. but i am looking something like " what content i am seeing in browser " i want as PDF.

Comment: What you do is equivalent to renaming a text file to `my.pdf` and expecting Adobe Reader to open `my.pdf` as a regular PDF. setting the headers is important to signal that you are going to send a PDF, but then you also have to send a PDF, not pure Text.